# How to update values on tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a window that would show the location of the mouse at all times by using pyautogui and tkinter. I am new to tkinter and python overall so I am not quite sure how to make it so that the values would keep updating in the window, if it is even possible. Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui as pag

window = Tk() 
window.geometry("200x200")
window.title("window")
window.config(background="#4ceefc")

coordinates = pag.position()

label1 = Label(window, text="mouse coordinates:")
label1.place(x=20, y=50)
    
label2 = Label(window, text=coordinates)
label2.place(x=30, y=90)
    
window.mainloop()
```

I tried using a while loop on the labels and window.mainloop() function but this did not work

Comment: Since `coordinates = pag.position()` only happens at run time you will need to first find a way to keep a loop dynamically check or let an event trigger the update like JRiggles mentioned below. On a side note it is not the easiest to maintain widget location with `place()` so I would recommend you learn `grid()` and or `pack()`. grid being my favorite to use.

Comment: @Mike-SMT +1 for `pack()` - you'll have a much easier time creating consistent user interfaces this way!

Comment: ***I tried using a while loop***. This is because the while loop essentially freezes the main loop so nothing can be updated during that time the while loop is active. Understand that tkinter is a single threaded application and not able to handle multiple loops without blocking the main loop.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Well said! Now, that's not to say that you *can't* use while loops in a tkinter app, but you'll more than likely have to resort to some `threading` kung fu that's unnecessary here ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `StringVar()` to store the coords, and then assign it to the label's `textvariable`. You can then bind a `'<Motion>'` handler to your root window to update the label whenever the mouse moves.

```
coord_var = StringVar(window)


def on_mousemove(event):
    coord_var.set(f'Mouse coordinates: {event.x}, {event.y}')


label1 = Label(window, textvariable=coord_var)
label1.place(x=20, y=50)
window.bind('<Motion>', on_mousemove)
```

Unless you're using pyautogui for something else, you can get away without it for this.

Comment: Lambda is not needed here. Simply reference the function. `window.bind('<Motion>', on_mousemove)`. A Lambda is also probably not something a new coder fully understands so if you are going to use a lambda as an example it might be a good idea to describe exactly what it is and why it is useful. In this case if you wanted to use a lambda it would be more like this: `window.bind('<Motion>', lambda event: coord_var.set(f'Mouse coordinates: {event.x}, {event.y}'))` and remove the function alltogether.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Fair point. I've removed the lambda. I tend to add them to most event bindings as it makes refactoring a bit more painless, but you're right in that it's not necessary here!

Comment: Note that `pag.position()` returns the mouse position in the screen, not relative to a certain window.  Also it works even the mouse cursor is outside the window.  Your solution does not.

Comment: @acw1668 Good to know! I'm not particularly familiar with pyautogui - that's a good point!